# Como ejecutar una Query en Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend

estoy tratando de que mi Backend en Spring Boot haga una Query de INNER JOIN para despues poder mostrar los datos de esa query en mi Frontend en Angular.

Spring Boot me dice:
"Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: persona is not mapped"
"persona is not mapped [SELECT name,apellidos,fechaturno,medico FROM persona c INNER JOIN turnos c1 ON c.id = c1.idturno]"

Entidad/Clase Persona

```
@Entity @Table(name="persona")
public class Persona {
    
    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) private int id;
    @Column private String name;
    @Column private String apellidos;
    
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "persona")
    List<Turno> turnos;
    

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public List<Turno> getTurnos() {
        return turnos;
    }

    public void setTurnos(List<Turno> turnos) {
        this.turnos = turnos;
    } 
}
```

PersonaServiceImp

```
@Service
public class PersonaServiceImp implements PersonaService{
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonaRepositorio repositorio; 
    
    @Override
    public List<Persona> listar() {
        return repositorio.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Persona listarId(int id) {
        return repositorio.findByid(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona add(Persona p) {
        return repositorio.save(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona edit(Persona p) {
        return repositorio.save(p);
    }

    @Override
    public Persona delete(int id) {
        Persona p = repositorio.findByid(id);
        if(p!=null){
           repositorio.delete(p); 
        }
        return p;
    }
    
}
```

Entidad/Clase Turno

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "turnos")
public class Turno {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idturno")
    private int idturno;
    
    
    @Column(name = "fechaturno")
    private String fechaturno;
    
    @Column(name = "medico")
    private String medico;
    
    
    @ManyToOne
    private Persona persona;

    public Turno(){
        
    }

    public int getIdturno() {
        return idturno;
    }

    public void setIdturno(int idturno) {
        this.idturno = idturno;
    }

    public String getFechaturno() {
        return fechaturno;
    }

    public void setFechaturno(String fechaturno) {
        this.fechaturno = fechaturno;
    }

    public String getMedico() {
        return medico;
    }

    public void setMedico(String medico) {
        this.medico = medico;
    }

    public Persona getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

    public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }   
}
```

Y ahora los Servicios/Repositorios
Persona Repositorio

```
public interface PersonaRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Persona, Integer> {
    //para listar todas las personas
    List<Persona>findAll();
    //para listar una persona
    Persona findByid(int id);// nota: el metodo findOne genera error grave es por eso que no se usa en su lugar usamos findByid
    //para guardar cambios nuevos o actualizar
    Persona save(Persona p);
    //para eliminar
    void delete(Persona p);
}
```

Persona Service

```
@Service
public interface PersonaService {
    // objeto de tipo List
    List<Persona>listar(); //listar todas las personas
    // objeto de tipo persona
    Persona listarId(int id); //listar una persona
    Persona add(Persona p);//agregar una persona
    Persona edit(Persona p);//editar una persona
    Persona delete(int id);//eliminar una persona
    //PRUEBA
    //Persona remove(int id);
    
}
```

y Turno Repository (Donde creo que tendria que hacer la Query)

```
@Repository
public interface TurnoRepository extends JpaRepository<Turno, Integer> {
    
    @Query("SELECT name,apellidos,fechaturno,medico FROM persona c INNER JOIN turnos c1 ON c.id = c1.idturno")
    List<Turno> findByIdturno(int idturno);
    
    Turno findById(int idturno);
    
    
    
}
```

Contexto: La relacion se trata de que una persona puede tener muchos turnos y al hacer una query sobre eso que traiga los nombres y apellidos de las personas con la fecha de turno y el medico que corresponde

pero no puedo lograr que haga la query

Comment: Ya probaste poner `Persona` con la P mayúscula?

Comment: Recién probé cambiando la P a mayuscula en la Query y me arroja esto:
"antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!"
"BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'turnoRepository' "
"QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'fechaturno' {originalText=fechaturno}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que te retorne instancias de objetos tipo `List<Turno>` el query debería ser así:

```
SELECT * FROM Turno
```

No te preocupes por seleccionar en el query los campos específicos nombre, medico, etc. puesto que la clase `Turno` ya tiene toda esa información, incluida instancias de tipo `Persona` dentro de ella.

Comment: Gracias, Me funciono la lógica de modificar la Query, no me funciono la sintaxis ya que debe ser formato JPQL la query, debe ser asi: "SELECT c FROM Turno c" y me trajo un JSON con toda la informacion relacionada, entonces con esto ya estaria echo? solo falta mostrar estos datos en Angular?